# What does "self.action" mean?

Tags: python

What does this mean?

`self.action = env.process(self.run())`

Is `.action` a default method?

I don't understand why this will automatically start the run process.

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.env = env
        # Start the run process everytime an instance is created.
        self.action = env.process(self.run())

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print('Start parking and charging at %d' % self.env.now)
            charge_duration = 5
            # We yield the process that process() returns
            # to wait for it to finish
            yield self.env.process(self.charge(charge_duration))
```

Comment: Presumably something else in your code is using the `action` property; it doesn't have any special meaning as such.

Comment: You're definiing a property called action, not sure what the question is

Comment: `env` and `action` are attributes of instances of the class.

Comment: The full code is here: https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simpy_intro/process_interaction.html     Really don't know why self.action can start the run process ><

Comment: What is starting the run process is presumably the call to `self.run()`

Answer (score 2):

> What does this mean?
>
> `self.action = env.process(self.run())`

It assigns the return value of calling the method `env.process` with the return value of calling the method `self.run` without arguments as an argument to the property `self.action`.

Since this is the `__init__`ializer, it also creates the property as a side-effect.

> Is `.action` a default method?

No, it's not a default method. In fact, it is neither a method (it is a property) and it isn't default (you are creating it right there). It is a property of `self` that is created and initialized in that line.

> I don't understand why this will automatically start the run process.

I have no idea what a "run process" is.

What it *will* do, is call the `self.run` method because that is used as an argument to the `env.process` method which is in turn used to initialize the `self.action` property. And since this code is in the initializer, it will indeed be called every time an object is instantiated.

Comment: I think I understand now. Thank you very much!!! :)